# Iteration of groups of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
A    B   C   D   E  ecc
x1A x1B x1C x1D x1E x1N
x2A x2B x2C x2D x2E x1N
xnA xnB xnC xnD xnE xnN
```

where A, B, C, D, E are the column names and xi are numbers. I would like to perform a certain operation considering stretches of 3 columns, so first considering columns A, B, C, then B, C, D as second iteration, C, D, E as third an so on. For example, I would like to calculate the variance from the sum of each column in each stretch of 3 (so first considering the columns A, B, C and calculate the sum of each column and calculate the variance; then do the same for B, C, D ecc). Could you suggest an effective way to do it in Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,8],"B":[3,8,4,1,2],"C":[8,3,1,2,4],"D":[9,2,5,6,3],"E":[5,9,3,5,1]})
l = len(data.columns)
no_of_columns_to_group = 3
start = 0
for i in range(0,l-no_of_columns_to_group+1):
    df_new = data.iloc[:,start:start+no_of_columns_to_group]
    print(df_new.columns)
    start += 1
    print(df_new.sum(axis=1).var())
```

Please note that the order of columns is important in this case. 
here is the output of the above program

```
Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object')
9.7
Index(['B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
21.7
Index(['C', 'D', 'E'], dtype='object')
30.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.rolling`:

```
df.sum().rolling(window=3).var()
```